# How to stop old item on my credit report from "refreshing"?

Tags: credit-report, credit-history

I found out here that bad items on your credit report are supposed to drop off after seven years. I have an unpaid credit card from 5 or 6 years ago that should drop off soon but apparently it was reported again in 2011. Does this mean that the clock started over from 2011? Since it's 5 or 6 years old is there any way I can stop it from resetting?

Comment: Did you make a payment (even a partial one) against the bad debt? That can cause the timer to restart.

Comment: No, I didn't make a payment. I haven't done anything to it.

Comment: Do you still owe money on this card, or was it paid, settled, eliminated in a bankrupcy, etc. ?